# Shuffling algorithm which is commutative on element deletion?

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

For an application that I'm writing (in a functional language), I'd like to implement a deterministic shuffling algorithm so that given the same seed, it will return the same shuffled array with some element at position X removed as it would had the element had not been in the array in the first place. Example: if `shuffle([1,2,3,4,5], seed) = [4,2,3,1,5]` then `shuffle([1,3,4,5], seed)` should return `[4,3,1,5]`. But before I try to reinvent the wheel, I must ask: does such an algorithm exist? (Also wondering if this property has some name). Thanks for any input.

Comment: Is `X` identified by its value or its initial position?

Comment: @ScottHunter X is identified by its initial position. I'll update the post to make it clear. In my case it does not matter since the array will be of the form [1,2,...,n], but it's good to have a generalized version.

Comment: It appears like you could solve it by mapping the initial values to initial shuffled positions. Afterwards, given a new list, find their mappings. If the seed changes, rebuild the mapping (alt. maintain a dictionary of mappings keyed by seed).

Comment: Is the idea to be able to take given subsets of a shuffled list (easy), or have an algorithm which, if run on a list and any of what happen to be a sublist of it, will yield results as you describe?

Comment: @Dinesh Sorry for not being clear, but the idea was to implement the second idea that Scott suggested in the comment above.

Comment: @Sid of course. From your example+comment above, the shuffled position of X depends on the value of X, determined on first usage. After that, even if the same list were shuffled (in common meaning of 'shuffle') and entered, the output must not change. So the machine has a memory, saying "X" maps "slot#" and any missing slots be crunched. One assumption is that X does not repeat (making the original a set). But it is an interesting problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shuffle yields either the original list or that list reversed (depending on the seed), it would have the property you describe.  Anything else, and not all of the sublists, when matched with their corresponding shuffling, will have the elements move the same way.  For example, consider `shuffle([1,2,3])`.  In the table below, each column is different shuffle; for each case, one of the 3 sub-lists has a shuffle that moves the elements differently than the other two.

```
shuffle([1,2,3])  = [1,3,2]  [2,1,3]  [2,3,1]  [3,1,2]
shuffle([1,2])    = [1,2]    [2,1]*   [2,1]    [1,2]*
shuffle([1,3])    = [1,3]    [1,3]    [3,1]    [3,1]
shuffle([2,3])    = [3,2]*   [2,3]    [2,3]*   [3,2]
```

Comment: Okay that is unfortunate. Can you prove that only trivial shuffles satisfy the given property?

Comment: @Sid This *is* a proof, though it uses the unstated hypothesis that the shuffling algorithm cannot inspect the elements (in static typing terms, they have a completely generic type).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This will also means then that the property will not work for non-trivial shuffles of lists larger than three either, since then the first three elements will not be in order.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat My comment was made before the post was edited. Now this is a complete proof because I consider the unstated hypothesis that you have given to be a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no duplicate values, you could sort them by value under a [pseudorandom function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), e.g., [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).